# tabulator showing empty text in rows

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Iam using `$(".table").tabulator("setData",data)` but the text is being shown as empty despite having the proper key for the column.

http://tabulator.info/docs/3.1 > Set data using an array

The above documentation is what I am using.

(attached a sample image below). Please do let me know if you need further information.
[image]

Comment: This would be easier to answer if we could  see the table definition and an example of what is in ```data```. Also any errors from browser console. Also you realize that ```$(".table").tabulator("setData",data)``` is a deprecated way to do this and only supported if you have the [jQuery Wrapper](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.7/jquery) loaded.

Comment: You appear to be using a version of Tabulator that is almost 3 years out of date, we are now on version 4.7. I would strongly recommend updating to the latest version to ensure correct function and optimal operation